# How can I use the conexion class in others php files?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have app in flutter that retrieve data from a mysql database managed with php, but I don't want to use static data for the conexion.

I change the conexion file to receive the conexion data from the app with an http post request and it do it's job. but when I try to recover data it returns nothing

This is my modified conexion file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$database = $_POST['database'];
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo("error");
}else{
    echo("conectado");
}
?>
```

and this is my retrieve file:

```
<?php

include "conn.php";

$queryResult=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM ventas");
$result=array();
while($fetchData=$queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[]=$fetchData;
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

so I need $conn to preserve the information a sended to it, to use it in other files

EDIT:

Well I think a found a way by adding a connection to all files

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$database = $_POST['database'];


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo("error");
}

$queryResult=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM ventas");
$result=array();
while($fetchData=$queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
    $result[]=$fetchData;
}
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

if the connection is correct, I save it into a class, with fields username, password, and database... the I send the variable in the post request

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a viable solution. Can you explain your reasons?

Comment: i need to access to different databases depending of the user information

Comment: Why do you think you need that? There are no applications that use this approach. Let me suggest you to do it the traditional way.

Comment: but they are asking me to use a different database for each user, o what do you suggest, I am not verry skilled on php

Comment: Who are "they" and what's their reason? Even with different databases, credentials are kept on the server anyway, not provided by a client. The usual way is to have a single database for all clients.

Comment: my bosses, and their reason, well it's the way we thought I was going to work... and we can't have a single database, because our clients have other clients, and we don't want to mix them

Comment: I would really really suggest you to ask a distinct question regarding this architecture.

Comment: I solve it, I think but I would like to hear your opinion about it, what I did is to add a conexion every time I retrieve information, and I also add, the credential from an object where I save the credentials the first time... I will add the edit, for a better visualization